# Get only file with given extension in directory

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a string variable pointing to a directory. In this directory is a single file with the extension `.xyz`. How do I get the path to this file, without knowing the file name itself?

I have the following code so far:

```
$dir = "C:\Temp\MyDir"
$xyzFiles = @(Get-ChildItem "$dir\*.xyz")
$file = $xyzFiles[0]
```

Is this "the way to go" in PowerShell? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would recommend using `Get-ChildItem`'s `-include` parameter:

```
Get-ChildItem $dir -include *.xyz
```

Comment: `-include *` works, returns all files, `-include *.RTF` doesn't seem to pick up the RTF files in the directory. ??

Comment: @AdamO It seems that you need to add the `-Recurse` flag.

Answer (score 5):

I would use `Get-ChildItem -Filter` and `Select-Object -First`:

```
$filepath = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter *.xyz |Select -First 1
```

Comment: Why is this answer having more upvotes than the `-include` solution above?

Comment: `-Filter` performs the fastest for me, so this solutions seems to work best

Answer (score 3):

In powerShell version 5, you can also try this:

```
Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse -Include *.xyz
```

Answer (score 3):

> **Simplest solution:**

```
Get-ChildItem $dir -File '*.xyz'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pipeline feature in Powershell to be a bit more efficient:

```
Get-ChildItem "$dir" | Where-Object {$_.FullName -match ".xyz$"}
```

This will grab a file with the extension of `.xyz`. If you have more than file you can further narrow it down.

Comment: why? `-include` is much better

Comment: This method works reliably where the option to use -include didn't work for me ..

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `Get-Item -LiteralPath (Resolve-Path "$dir\*.xyz")`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Get-ChildItem $dir -File | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ".xyz" }
```